# Formating a File to a listBox 5 lines at a time

Tags: c#, file, listbox, streamreader

stuck on a last minute assignment and could really really use a hand. 
i have a file that hold dna codons, 1 per line in a set of 3 EXAMPLE:

acg
att
atg
acc
etc...

i need to output these into a list box 5 at a time in the format:

Line 01: acg att atg acc agg
line 02: act tga tcg....etc

for all 1000 codons.

```
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reader = new StreamReader("DNA.txt");
        int counter = 0;




        do{

            counter++;
            s = reader.ReadLine();
            lstOut.Items.Add("Line " + counter.ToString("00") + ": " + s);


        }

        while (!reader.EndOfStream);
        reader.DiscardBufferedData();
        reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    }
```

this is currently all i have wrtten and as i am fairly new to c# i am not sure how to get these files to read out 5 at a time. the best i have got is the 15 charactars together but in this format

acgtcgaccagtcga

without the spaces

i tried a ReadBlock and had it set up to read every 25 charactars (not sure why it was taking 25 to come out with the 15 letter) but it kept crashing the 2nd time through the loop. due at 10:00 tonight if anyone has any ideas i would be so thankful!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this aproach

```
int max ;
int i ;
int numLine ;
int set ;
string line ;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("DNA.txt");

max = lines.Count() ;
i = 0 ;
numLine = 1 ;

while(i < max)
{
    line = string.Format("Line {0}:",numLine.toString("00")) ;

    //logic to handle case where your file does not have multiple of 5 number of lines
    for(set = 1; (i < max) && (set <= 5); set++)
    {
        line += lines[i] + " ";
        i++ ;
    }
    lstOut.Items.Add(line) ;
    numLine++ ;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the reason for defining variables at the begining instead of where you first use them?

Comment: Well I find it highly unreadable. It also makes refactoring a lot harder. For example in while you assign to line variable. Why it is not defined inside while? It is not used anywhere else. Same with set variable.

Comment: I'm not talking about renaming variables but for example extract method refactoring. Refactoring is about converting your code when it is already written. Not writing it differently from the beginning.

Comment: that worked perfectly. thank you so much. first real big project with c#. stuck on tryign to get that to work for hours. thank you so much

Comment: @user3076057 please mark this as answer. And keep practicing your c# skills maybe in a few months this will not look as such a big challenge/proyect

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this? :

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("DNA.txt");

for(int i=0;i<lines.Count();i+=5)
{
    lstOut.Items.Add(string.Format("Line {0}:{1}",
                     (i/5).ToString("00"),
                     string.Join(" ",lines.Skip(i).Take(5))));
}
```

Comment: @MauricioGracia it will do the grouping now

Comment: i need it to print out 5 sets of codons per line so

Comment: Line 01: acg act acg cga tcg

Comment: line 02: atg acg atc cga tga  so that each set of 5 codons is its own line